# Javascript element style

Tags: javascript, css

I'm curious why this one

```
<div class = "overlay">
    fdsfsd
</div>
.overlay{
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color:red;
}
alert(document.getElementsByClassName("overlay")[0].style.width);
```

is not alerting nothing. Of course I can write `<div style = "width:100px">`
then everthing works fine, but it is not good for me, I need css.
Here you can find a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mondayguy/9kwap3zy/)

So exact question is: why this code is not alerting width of div and how alert it if width is given by css?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JavaScript `.style` only relates to inline styles on the element.

See [Documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/dom_obj_style.asp).

If you want to get the width of an element you should use `offsetWidth`.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("overlay")[0].offsetWidth
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9kwap3zy/7/

Answer (score 10):

As noted elsewhere, the problem is that `HTMLElement.style` retrieves the values from the `style` attribute of the element; as you're setting your style with CSS, you need to instead use `window.getComputedStyle(element, null).width`:

```js
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("overlay")[0],
  width = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).width;

console.log(width);
```

```css
.overlay {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  fdsfsd
</div>
```

References:

- [`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style).
- [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle).

Comment: Don't know who down-voted this :/ but might want to `parseInt`

Comment: @Digigizmo: neither do I, it's a little annoying (but presumably they have their reasons). I'm not sure about using `parseInt()` (or `parseFloat()`), simply because the width without the units (even if JavaScript always returns lengths in `px`) seems a little meaningless; and there's no mention of wanting 'just' the numbers. If the question's updated to request that then I'll update, as-is it seems premature.

Comment: ye, I only mentioned it for awareness - generally you only fetch the width when you want to manipulate it or use the value in some other calculation.

Answer (score 1):

The style gives access only to information which is put into `elem.style`. In your example style doesn’t tell anything about the margin defined in CSS. Use [getComputedStyle()](http://javascript.info/tutorial/styles-and-classes-getcomputedstyle#getcomputedstyle-and-currentstyle).

```
var computedStyle = getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByClassName("overlay")[0], null)

alert(computedStyle.width);
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/9kwap3zy/17/)

Answer (score 0):

The .style is inline `style="width:100px;"` only...

If it's in CSS (rather than inline) you need getComputedStyle -

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle